# How do you get child bands in ultragrid without using related tables in a dataset?

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using linq to pull back an object (i.e. customer) that might have a collection of other objects(customer.orders).  I would be nice if I can pass this list of customers to the ultragrid and a hierarchical view of customers and thier orders displayed on databind.  When I try this, I just get customers.  Anyone know how to get this to work with non dataset objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out.  IList collection works and will create bands for properties of your domain object if it is an `IList<T>`.  Just make sure that`DisplayLayout.ViewStyle                 = ViewStyle.MultiBand`.

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me with a dataset with nested List collections, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following and it didn't work:

```
DisplayLayout.ViewStyle = ViewStyle.MultiBand
```

I read from [this blog](http://puzzlefun.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!B8D1279D8C4B76E5!186.entry) that it must be `List` and not `IList` in order to work, and it did.

Answer (score 0):

We work with our own custom datasource for grid, so we first create a structure of bands and then we initialize data OnDemand, handling events
InitializeDataRow
InitializeRowsCollection
CellDataRequested

We use Tags to navigate through the structure.